# HTML Date Selector

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, datetime, form

I made a date selector in HTML, which accounts for leap years and the number of days in each month. I am relatively new to javascript / HTML so please critique it as much as possible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Date Selector</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            function clear(select) {
                for(var i = select.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    select.remove(i);
                }
            }

            function createMonths() {
                var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
                var select = document.getElementById("month");
                for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = months[i];
                    select.add(option);
                }
            }

            function createDays(days) {
                var select = document.getElementById("day");

                var index = select.options.selectedIndex;
                if(index < 0) index = 0;
                if(index >= days) index = days - 1;

                clear(select);
                for(var day = 1; day <= days; day++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = day;
                    select.add(option);
                }

                select.options.selectedIndex = index;
            }

            function createYears(start, end) {
                var select = document.getElementById("year");
                for(var year = end; year >= start; year--) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = year;
                    select.add(option);
                }
            }

            function leapYear(year) {
                if(year % 400 == 0) return true;
                if(year % 100 == 0) return false;
                return year % 4 == 0;
            }

            function update() {
                var month = document.getElementById("month").options.selectedIndex + 1;

                if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
                    createDays(31);
                }
                else if(month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
                    createDays(30);
                }
                else {
                    var options = document.getElementById("year").options;
                    var year = options[options.selectedIndex].text;

                    if(leapYear(year)) {
                        createDays(29);
                    }
                    else {
                        createDays(28);
                    }
                }
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                var today = new Date();
                var year = today.getFullYear();

                createMonths();
                createDays(31);
                createYears(year - 100, year);
            };
        </script>

        <select id="month" onchange="update()"></select>
        <select id="day"></select>
        <select id="year" onchange="update()"></select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not gonna wrote an answer from my phone while I'm poopin but you should put these functions together on a constructor or class and separate the DOM from the logic so you can reuse this.

Comment: @bstrauch24 This is incorrectly reporting February as having 29 days in 2001-3, 2005-7, 2009-11, 2013-15, and 2017 (that I've checked), and is also incorrectly reporting February as having 28 days in 2004, 2008, 2012 and 2016. Perhaps you meant `return year % 4 === 0;` in the `leapYear` method.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Can you elaborate on how you would separate this into a javascript class? I like the idea of reusability, but how would you start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't pay much attention to your logic, but focusing on this question:

> Can you elaborate on how you would separate this into a javascript class? I like the idea of reusability, but how would you start?

I would start by abstracting the DOM references in the code. Maybe just pass it a single div or span and then generate the select boxes dynamically for maximum reusability.

Then I would combine the methods into a class or constructor of some sort because if you have a function in your code called `clear`, for example, later on you might have a hard time figuring out what that does. `datepicker.clear()` is much more descriptive than just `clear()`

Here's an example of how you might accomplish this:

```
function DatePicker(element, days, startyear, endyear) {
  // Create the markup
  this.monthElement = document.createElement("select");
  this.dayElement = document.createElement("select");
  this.yearElement = document.createElement("select");
  this.monthElement.onChange = this.update;
  this.yearElement.onChange = this.update;
  element.appendChild(this.monthElement);
  element.appendChild(this.dayElement);
  element.appendChild(this.yearElement);

  this.createMonths();
  this.createDays(days);
  this.createYears(startyear, endyear);
}

DatePicker.prototype.clear = function(select) {
  for (var i = select.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    select.remove(i);
  }
};

DatePicker.prototype.createMonths = function() {
  var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = months[i];
    this.monthElement.add(option);
  }
};

DatePicker.prototype.createDays = function(days) {
  var index = this.dayElement.options.selectedIndex;
  if (index < 0) index = 0;
  if (index >= days) index = days - 1;

  this.clear(this.dayElement);
  for (var day = 1; day <= days; day++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = day;
    this.dayElement.add(option);
  }

  this.dayElement.options.selectedIndex = index;
};

DatePicker.prototype.createYears = function(start, end) {
  for (var year = end; year >= start; year--) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = year;
    this.yearElement.add(option);
  }
};

DatePicker.prototype.leapYear = function(year) {
  if (year % 400 == 0) return true;
  if (year % 100 == 0) return false;
  return year % 4 == 0;
};

DatePicker.prototype.update = function() {
  var month = this.monthElement.options.selectedIndex + 1;

  if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
    this.createDays(31);
  } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
    this.createDays(30);
  } else {
    var options = this.yearElement.options;
    var year = options[options.selectedIndex].text;

    if (this.leapYear(year)) {
      this.createDays(29);
    } else {
      this.createDays(28);
    }
  }
};
```

Then you can call it like this

```
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();

// Send it a reference to a single element and create the markup in the constructor, 
// That way you don't have to rely on the user creating the correct markup
var dp = document.getElementById('datePicker');
var dPicker = new DatePicker(dp, 31, year - 100, year);
```

[Here's a working demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/xaazvux9/1/)